# QML / C++ Optional Properties

Tags: c++, qml

How can I declare a property that only exists at some point in time?

My first attempt was to implement a method `getThingy()` that returns a pointer to thingy if it exists and null otherwise. I would have a signal that notifies when the property changes.

```
Q_PROPERTY(Thingy* thingy READ thingy NOTIFY thingyChanged)
```

However when I access this in QML the QML run time keeps complaining:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'thingy' of null
```

If I want to have an optional property whats the QML way to declare it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that, but as you can see you can't access a property from a `null` value. You have to check if it's non null first.

This can be done the same as in javascript:

- `thingy ? thingy.property : defaultValue`
- `thingy && thingy.property // returns null if thingy is null`
- ...

Comment: I am aware of this, but this is probably not best practice in QML (accessing a null property causes a warning at runtime). Is there a concept of optional properties in QML?

Comment: Accessing a property of a null value causes a warning at runtime, but the above snippet. No there's no concept of optional properties in QML (except a nullable property like you did).